# Displaying images in a matrix in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am inserting images into a `div` dynamically, but they are all appearing one-by-one vertically. My `div` is a rectangular box and the list has four elements. I want my images to appear in matrix form.

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="box" style="margin: -399px -69px -47px 857px;" >

    <c:forEach items="${mapi}" var="employee" >

        <a onclick="getImages('${employee.id}')">
            <img id="image" name="${employee.id}" 
                style='display:block; width:99px;height:100px;margin: 54px 116px 20px;'                 
                src='data:image/jpeg;base64,${employee.encodedString}' />
        </a>

   </c:forEach >

</div>
```

Is there any way?

Comment: you have to change the `display:block` to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: no change in appearance.

Comment: can you try giving a `style='display: inline-block'` to `<a>`

Comment: No dude i am getting the same result.

Comment: create a class in css `border: 1px solid red;` apply to every element and check the size of each element is as you desire. Also try giving a high value width to the parent `div`. just some thougts..

Comment: please recreate the issue in jsfiddle or similar if you still facing the issue.

Comment: ok Thank you redflar.

Comment: I am able to get using jquery by adding 4 classes and in each iteration adding the new class to new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get this by adding 4 classes and in each iteration adding the new class to the new image using the iteration number.

```
< c:forEach items="${mapi}" var="employee" varStatus="loopCounter" >
   < a onclick="getImages('${employee.id}')" class="imagepos${loopCounter.count}" style="display:inline-block;">

      <img id="image" name="${employee.id}" style='width:99px;height:100px;' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,${employee.encodedString}' />

   < /a>
< /c:forEach>
```

I have added four different margins for four classes as `.imagepos1,imagepos2...`